# AWK rename multiple lines

Tags: linux, awk, rename

How to rename multiple lines in a text file using AWK?

For instance the first and the third, from

```
x y z
0 1 2
q w e
```

to

```
a b c
0 1 2
g h i
```

The script would look like this,

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {}
NR==1 { ...replace... } 
NR==3 { ...more replace... } 
END {}
```

Comment: What is the source of these replacements? Are they just hard-coded? Are you having a problem targeting the specific lines? Have you tried anything yet? Much more detail is needed here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to replace fixed number of lines with fixed strings, then this script should do the trick:

```
NR==1 { $0 = "a b c" } 
NR==3 { $0 = "g h i" } 
{ print }
```